# Using kapt with multiplatform subproject

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform, kapt

I have the following project structure

```
root-project
│   build.gradle.kts
│
└───multiplatform-project
│   │   build.gradle.kts 
│   │
│   └───src
│       │   kotlin
|       |   js
│   
└───simple-kotlin-project
    │   build.gradle.kts
```

So there are 3 projects in total (3 `build.gradle.kts` files).

1. Here is the **root** project `build.gradle.kts`

   ```
   plugins {
       kotlin("jvm") version kotlinVersion apply false
       kotlin("kapt") version kotlinVersion apply false
       kotlin("multiplatform") version kotlinVersion apply false
   }

   subprojects {
       apply<JavaPlugin>()

       if (name.contains("multiplatform-project")) {
           apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform")
       } else {
           apply(plugin = "kotlin")
       }

       apply(plugin = "kotlin-kapt")

       dependencies {
           implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
           implementation(kotlin("reflect"))
           implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.0-M2")

           implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25")
           implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3")
           implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")

           testImplementation("junit:junit:$jUnitVersion")
       }
   }
   ```
2. Here is the simple kotlin project that uses *kapt* and that **works**

   ```
   val jacksonVersion: String by project

   dependencies {
       implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:$jacksonVersion")
       implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:$jacksonVersion")
       implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:$jacksonVersion")
       implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:$jacksonVersion")

       kapt(project(":generator")) // THIS WORKS!!!
   }
   ```
3. Now my question is how to make this work in the multiplatorm project which looks like that

   ```
   val jacksonVersion: String by project
   val ktorVersion: String by project

   kotlin {
       jvm {
           val main by compilations.getting {
               kotlinOptions {
                   jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
               }

               compileKotlinTask
               output
           }
       }
       js {}

       sourceSets {
           val jvmMain by getting {
               dependencies {
                   implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:$jacksonVersion")
                   implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:$jacksonVersion")
                   implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:$jacksonVersion")

                   implementation("io.ktor:ktor-html-builder:$ktorVersion")
                   implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktorVersion")

                   kapt(project(":generator")) // THIS DOESN'T WORK!!!
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Here is the error that I see in IDEA

[image]

That is not a phantom error. If I run gradle build, I get the following error:

> build.gradle.kts:38:22: Type mismatch: inferred type is ProjectDependency but Action was expected

So, the question boils down to how do I run **kapt** plugin on the kotlin sourceSet the same way that I can do it in a simple kotlin project by adding it to dependencies of the project.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you've already found the [answer](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/issues/1372#issuecomment-515285784) your looking for, but let me post it here for any other users that might be interested in working around the issue.

The issue is mainly caused by `kapt` resolving to the `Project` extension registered under the kapt name by the Kotlin Gradle Plugin. 
Because of this, the extension to declare a dependency in the kapt Configuration isn't available in the `kotlin.sourceSets.jvm().compilations["main"].defaultSourceSet.dependencies` scope.

The workaround consist in manually getting the configuration and adding the project dependency to it:

```
sourceSets {
    val jvmMain by getting {
      dependencies {
        ...
        configurations.get("kapt").dependencies.add(project(":generator"))
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using Gradle kotlin scripts, you'll have do do something slightly different:

`configurations["kapt"].dependencies.add(project.dependencies.create("com.example:foo:1.0"))`

Answer (score 5):

For anyone looking to add a `kapt` dependency, for example, android's hilt-compiler, to the androidMain sourceSet you can:

```kotlin
sourceSets {
    val androidMain by getting {
        dependencies {
            // declare the implementation for the compiler
            implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.37")

            // configure kapt to utilize
            configurations.getByName("kapt").dependencies.add(
                DefaultExternalModuleDependency(
                    "com.google.dagger",
                    "hilt-compiler",
                    "2.37"
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue in kmm project

```kotlin
//you can also consider this to add into your buildSrc
//import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.DependencyHandlerScope
fun DependencyHandlerScope.kapt(dependencyNotation:String){
    add("kapt", dependencyNotation)
}

kotlin{...}

android{
   ....
   dependencies {
        implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")
        kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")
    }
}
```